# How to get visible element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have one hidden div and inside it i have visible span. I want to alert some text if span does not have display none property.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            if($('span').is(':visible')){
                alert(0)
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fa" style="display:none">
        <span>sdf</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And what's the question ?

Comment: You seem to be forgetting to import jquery.

Comment: I have import jquery. I just did not posted

Comment: I want output alert(0) but it does nothing

Comment: If the `div` is not visible, the `span` inside it is also not visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your alert doesn't fire is that your `span` isn't visible.  The fact that it is contained within an element that has `display: none` means that it will not be shown.  If you specifically want to check if it is `display: none` itself, use `css`.

```
        if($('span').css('display') != "none"){
            alert(0)
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Your `<span>` is a child of a `<div>` that's hidden with `display: none` - that means neither the `<div>`, nor the `<span>` consume any space in the document.

Which means that your `<span>` is hidden and your script has no errors - it does exactly what it suppose to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't import jQuery.

Add this in your `head` element :

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that an HTML file must also have HTML opening and closing elements, and preferably a doctype. The following file works :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      if($('span').is(':visible')){
       alert(0)
    }})
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fa" style="display:none">
<span>sdf</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it does nothing, as your span is in a not displayed div.

Now, if you want to precisely know if your element does't have the style display=none set directly on it, test it like this :

```
if ($('span').get(0).style.display!='none') {
```

[Demonstration](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/14324424.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the div containing the span element has display:none as property, try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gracedescending/qxM8h/), you just put display:hidden instead of none and the JS works.

```
<div class="fa" style="display:hidden"><span>sdf</span></div>
```